# Converting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Can anyone please help me with converting `1218100860` to `datetime`?

I tried like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(s,1218100860, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 101)
```

and it works but when I try like this, it throws an error:

```
SELECT 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(s, rd.Request_Date, '1970-01-01 00:00:00'), 101) 
FROM 
     dbo.RequestDetails rd
```

where `Request_Date` is the column where the the value has to be converted to `datetime`
the error is:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: hi, rd.Request_Date is timestamp or dateTime?

Comment: that column's datatype is varchar. i need to convert it to datetime and store in another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what RDBMS you're using (maybe sQL Server?), but:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function

This means that argument 2 (`rd.Request_Date`) should not be a `varchar`.
Since in your first example you used an integer and it worked,
then it seems you just have to convert `rd.Request_Date` to integer and it should work,
like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(s,CONVERT(INT, rd.Request_Date), '1970-01-01 00:00:00'),101 )
```